# Hide and show panel based on selection from drop down list

Tags: javascript, html

I created a script that should show and hide a some items depending on the same choices selected from 5 drop down lists. This choice from this drop down list is the exact same. So i was just checking to see if my solution could possibly be simplified

HTML:

```
<label for="ddlGift1">Gift #1</label>
         <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlGift1" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="True" ClientIDMode="Static" > 
             <asp:ListItem Value="--" Text="--" />
         </asp:DropDownList>   
<label for="ddlGift2">Gift #2</label>
         <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlGift2" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="True" ClientIDMode="Static" > 
             <asp:ListItem Value="--" Text="--" />
         </asp:DropDownList>
<label for="ddlGift3">Gift #3</label>
         <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlGift3" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="True" ClientIDMode="Static" > 
             <asp:ListItem Value="--" Text="--" />
         </asp:DropDownList>   
<label for="ddlGift4">Gift #4</label>
         <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlGift4" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="True" ClientIDMode="Static" > 
             <asp:ListItem Value="--" Text="--" />
         </asp:DropDownList>     
<label for="ddlGift5">Gift #5</label>
         <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlGift5" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="True" ClientIDMode="Static" > 
             <asp:ListItem Value="--" Text="--" />
         </asp:DropDownList>
```

JS:

```
   var gift1 = $('#ddlGift1');
   var gift1 = $('#ddlGift1');
   var gift2 = $('#ddlGift2');
   var gift3 = $('#ddlGift3');
   var gift4 = $('#ddlGift4');
   var gift5 = $('#ddlGift5');

   showHide();
   gift1.change(function () {
    showHide();
});
gift2.change(function () {
    showHide();
});
gift3.change(function () {
    showHide();
});
gift4.change(function () {
    showHide();
});
gift5.change(function () {
    showHide();
});
 function showHide() {
var gift1 = $('#ddlGift1');
var gift2 = $('#ddlGift2');
var gift3 = $('#ddlGift3');
var gift4 = $('#ddlGift4');
var gift5 = $('#ddlGift5');
var vsity = $('#shvarsity');



if ((gift1.children("option:selected").text())||(gift2.children("option:selected").text())||(gift3.children("option:selected").text())||(gift4.children("option:selected").text())||(gift5.children("option:selected").text()) == "Varsity Club")
{

    vsity.show();

} else {

    vsity.hide();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class to all of the "gift" elements, like

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="ddlGift1" class="gift" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="True" ClientIDMode="Static" > 
    <asp:ListItem Value="--" Text="--" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Then the JS would look something like

```
var gifts = $('.gift');
showHide();

gifts.change(function () {
    showHide();
});

function showHide() {
for (i in gifts) {
    if (gifts[i].children("option:selected").text() == "Varsity Club")
    {
        vsity.show();
    } else {
        vsity.hide();
    }
}
}
```